# Ubuntu17.10.1 freezes on boot

Tags: boot, lockup

I get message [     *] A start job is running for Hold until boot process finishes up (25s / no limit)_

the astrix is red.
when I attempt to boot Ubuntu 17.10.1.
Ubuntu 16.04.4 works
System is a toshiba satellite laptop with AMD turion x2 64 CPU and 4 gb ram